# How can I change the type of significance bar on ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, significance, ggpubr

I have a ggplot that displays significance with downward brackets, but my boss wants them to have tick marks going up and down (see image below). As well, my boss wants the "ns" to be capital. Is there a good way to control this without having to it manually? I am making 10 plots total.

```
p <- ggplot(LessCountS, aes(x=Type, y=DC)) + 
  geom_dotplot(aes(fill= Type), binwidth = 4.5,
               binaxis = "y", 
               stackdir = "center",
               color = "black" 
  ) +
  theme_gray ()+
  labs(x="", y = "Cell Count (cells/uL")+
  ggtitle("Dendritic cells") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("HC" = "Controls", "IN" = "Inpatients",
                            "OUT" = "Outpatients")) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 14), legend.text=element_text(size=12), 
        legend.position = "none", text = element_text(family = "Calibri"), axis.text = element_text(size=14),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 14)) +
  #scale_fill_brewer(palette="Purples") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#CCCCCC", "#990066", "#3366CC")) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = median, fun.ymin = median, fun.ymax = median,
               geom = "crossbar", width = 0.35) +
  stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons, label.y = , label = "p.signif", size = 5)
p
```

[image]

I would like the plot to look more like this: 
[image]

Notice the difference in the significance denotations, I wan to make the dendritic plot look like the neutrophil plot.

Thanks in advance,
S

Comment: For the capitalization of the label "NS", take a look at the documentation of `stat_compare_means` which shows that you can use the argument `symnum.args` to put customized labels indicating significance cutoffs. For the bar tips going in both directions, I don't think there is a built-in option for that in the `stat_compare_means` function. You might need to write your own function or add them manually.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you! Would you also happen to know how I can extend the graph a bit so that the significance bars/text, aren't so close the top edge?

Comment: You can add a line somewhere with `scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,170), expand=c(0,0))` that will extend the y-axis to the limits. `expand=c(0,0)` just means not to pad the axis even more than the limits you set.

Comment: Perfect, worked like a charm. Last question, is there a way to make the * (asterisks) larger without increasing the size of the NS? As you can see in my graph vs the model the proportions are different.

Comment: I think since you need so much customization it's probably going to be easier for you to write your own code to do all this manually rather than using `stat_compare_means`

Comment: I would have to agree. I am using ```geom_segment``` and  ```geom_text``` and though its gonna take much longer, it looks much better.